# Matching hashes, eql? returns true, but has_key? returns false

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I'm on Ruby 2.2.1 and have the following situation:

```
a = ... # some object
h = ... # some hash

p h.size #=> 1
p h.keys.first.hash == a.hash #=> true
p h.keys.first.eql?(a) #=> true
p h.has_key?(a) #=> false
```

How is this possible? I thought that the hashes matching and `eql?` returning true were the only conditions for keys to be considered equal.

---

**Edit:** Here's the full program. But please note that **I'm not asking how to fix it**—I know how. **I'm asking why Ruby behaves that way!** Because I'm confused as to why the API contracts of `Hash` count for nothing in this situation.

```
class A
  attr_reader :x

  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  MY_HASH = { A.new(5) => 'foo' }

  def ==(other)
    @x == other.x
  end

  alias_method :eql?, :==

  def hash
    @x
  end
end

a = A.new(5)
h = A::MY_HASH

p h.size #=> 1
p h.keys.first.hash == a.hash #=> true
p h.keys.first.eql?(a) #=> true
p h.has_key?(a) #=> false
```

Comment: Can you post the objects that behave in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time when you create `MY_HASH` the new `hash` function of `A` is not yet defined so `MY_HASH` will use the default one when creating an index of it's values. When you later define a new hash function it will change how the objects are hashed BUT NOT AUTOMATICALLY update the index in the already existing Hash `MY_HASH`.

You solve this my initializing `MY_HASH` after you have defined the new `hash` method for class `A` or by running `MY_HASH.rehash`

```
p h.has_key?(a) #=> false
A::MY_HASH.rehash
p h.has_key?(a) #=> true
```